# Can I turn off the new item notification?

Tags: steam

Once in a while, I get new trading cards from playing games. I am really not into the whole Steam trading card thing, and the constant green notification icon in the top right corner, both in the client and on the web interface, annoys me to no end. Is there a way for me to turn off the notification? I don't care if I keep getting cards or not, but I'd like to not have that green thing there every time I open Steam.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot disable this notification at this time. However, you can make a [suggestion on the Steam Forums](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/) about it.